# First page number is not appearing

Tags: revtex

The first page number is not appearing however the subsequent page numbers are. It is just the first page number that doesn't appear and I am not sure why.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prb,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  

\onecolumngrid
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: At the beginning of your document : "\thispagestyle{plain}".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your document example is not complete. Pleas check your document example, and add what is missing that we can compile as it is. Abstract are usually together with article title on separate page, which is not numbered.

Comment: The class purposedly does `\thispagestyle{titlepage}` when processing `\maketitle` and this page style is essentially the same as `empty`. So the American Physical Society seems not to want the page number on the top page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `revtex4-2` class calls `\titleblock@produce` when processing `\maketitle`. In turn, this macro does

```
\thispagestyle{titlepage}\label{FirstPage}
```

Later on, it does

```
\def\ps@titlepage{\ps@empty}%
```

which effectively makes the `titlepage` page style the same as the `empty` page style, in which the page number is not printed.

The indirection is because in this way the document class that's eventually used for the final printing can define the `titlepage` style as wished for the particular journal.

You shouldn't change the default behavior if you're submitting a paper to some journal that requires `revtex4-2`. They *want* no page number on the top page.

If you're using the class for your own purposes, add

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

after `\maketitle`. But remember to remove it when submitting or the paper could even be rejected for failure to comply with the rules.